# How to change axis labels' order/sorting in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

When I'm making a line chart in Spotfire to get the trend, it automatically sorts my x-axis labels. Is there any way in which I get the same order of the labels as in my data file ?? (Labels are time periods, in MMMYYYY format)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a line chart with a date as the category axis, it only makes sense for the category axis to be sorted by date. Otherwise, the chart would essentially be a scatter chart. One way to group this is to use BinBy<...> function or apply another category on top of your date column so that it segments it.